# Setting a calling channel between 2 iPhone connected on common WiFi route

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sip

I am working an app that has a requirement that an iPhone connected with a WiFi router can setup a voice/video call with another iPhone connected on the same WiFi router. I read about SIP for that but have a doubt whether that'll help in this or not. Is there any sdk for to implement this feature in Objective-C?